# Better way to wrap a Lucene TokenFilter?

Tags: java, lucene

I'm finding myself frustrated trying to develop code that builds on existing Lucene TokenFilter classes. The classes all seem to be declared final, which means I can't subclass them, and I'm not sure I'm seeing the motivation for that.

But one of the main things I needed to do I think I've managed. I'd just like to know if there's a cleaner way to accomplish what I'm after.

The specific requirement is to be able to establish a set of "preserved words" that represent tokens that should survive in the token stream even in the presence of token filters that would normally remove them. For this I only care about filters that subclass `FilteringTokenFilter`.

So my approach is to implement a class, `PreservingFilterWrapper`, which wraps a `FilteringTokenFilter` instance. (`PreserveAttribute` is an attribute that is established by an upstream filter to identify tokens that match preserved words.)

```
    public class PreservingFilterWrapper extends FilteringTokenFilter {

    private final FilteringTokenFilter wrappedFilter;
    private final Method wrappedFilterAccept;
    private final TokenStream upstream;

    public PreservingFilterWrapper(Version version, FilteringTokenFilter wrappedFilter, TokenStream upstream)  {
        super(version, upstream);
        this.wrappedFilter = wrappedFilter;
        try {
            this.wrappedFilterAccept = wrappedFilter.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("accept");
            wrappedFilterAccept.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        this.upstream = upstream;
    }

    private final PreserveAttribute preserveAtt = addAttribute(PreserveAttribute.class);

    @Override
    protected boolean accept() throws IOException {
        if (preserveAtt.isPreserved()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            try {
                return (Boolean) wrappedFilterAccept.invoke(wrappedFilter);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This works. But I'm really not all that happy about violating declared protections (using `getDeclaredMethod` to get access to the wrapped filter's `accept()` method, which is declared as `protected`). Then again, I'm having the same hard time understanding why this method needs to be `protected` as I am understanding why all these filter classes need to be `final`.

I'm also not thrilled about the odd plumbing required here: the wrapped filter and the wrapper both need to be instantiated with the same `TokenStream` object so that they'll share attribute instances. But the wrapped filter isn't really acting like a filter - its `incrementToken()` method is never invoked, for instance. I just want access to its `accept()` logic. If the classes weren't final, of course, I could subclass whichever filters I wanted to use, and this would all be easy.

Hence my overall question. Am I just missing a cleaner way of approaching this problem? Or are Lucene's protections really forcing my hand? And if the latter, is there a good reason for these protections, or is it something that might be loosened up in some later version given some lobbying effort?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly the part about creating a wrapper class to undo the filtering for selected words sounds like a good approach to me, though you might have a look through the academic literature to see if anyone has come up with a more elegant method of handling this issue.

As for the protections, I can't really speak to those -- for me, making too much stuff 'final' or 'private' always seems to lead to grief when finishing up my unit-testing.